# Run script inside a Docker container from the windows 10 host in cmd or powershell

Tags: docker

I need to use a program written by someone else within a Docker container (Docker Desktop v19.03.12 in windows 10). I made a script file (bt.sh) to run the third party program with the correct options. It sits in the container, in the folder /root/FrMG_Files/, together with the data files to be processed.
I can run the script without problems from within the container (./bt.sh) from the folder /root/FrMG_Files.

I want to automate the process by running the script from the windows host as part of a larger sequence.
In windows cmd or powershell, I can get the file list with :

```
docker exec -it -w /root/FrMG_Files container_id dir
```

I tried to run the script with many variations such as

```
docker exec -it -w /root/FrMG_Files container_id ./bt.sh
docker exec -it -w /root/FrMG_Files container_id './bt.sh --cmd “command” host''
docker exec -it -w /root/FrMG_Files container_id "./bt.sh"
```

but none of these worked. I get the error message:
*OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec format error": unknown*

The script runs with

```
docker exec -it -w /root/FrMG_Files container_id bash ./bt.sh
```

The first line of the script is *echo "I am in the container"* and this works.  The other commands do not work (command not found).

I would greatly appreciate some help on this.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You want to run a shell script, so using bash makes sense

Comment: For windows host try to use a windows script file .. may be a .cmd file

Comment: I have texts to analyse which are stored in Excel. A VBA script makes txt files and a bash script, copies the files and script to the Docker container. I have a syntax analyser in the container. The script calls the analyser with the options. Then, another VBA script makes a tar file using Docker exec in cmd, copies the tar file to the host, extracts it and copies the results of the in excel for multi-variate analysis. It want to run the bash script using docker exec to have one VBA program. Now I run VBA code, go to the container to run the script, and go back to VBA to run the last part.